# How can I find a needle in a haystack, and show the entire line?

Tags: php, line

How can I find a needle in a haystack, and show the entire line?

log.txt :

> Log #5731: JohnDoe has arrested JaneDoe
>
> Log #5732: DonDoe has arrested JaneDoe

I want to search for "JohnDoe" and display the whole line
Log #5731: JohnDoe has arrested JaneDoe.

Also, if there's several logs for one person I want to show them all

Comment: Iterate over all lines and show if `/JohnDoe/` matches?

Answer (score 0):

You could explode your text by newline.
Then search for what you want using `array_search` method and have the key of that element in the array.

Tho I wouldn't recommend that first solution, if your log is or becomes big (which should be the case for most logs), since the entire log has to be loaded and put into an array. That eats up a massive ammount of resources.

I'd rather do like

```
<?php
$logfilepath = 'path/to/log.txt';

function searchLog($logfilepath, $searchQuery) {
    $fileresource = fopen($logfilepath, 'r');
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        //now search in buffer
        if(strpos($buffer, $searchQuery) !== false) {
            return $buffer;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: If you want to find all occurences:

```
<?php
$logfilepath = 'path/to/log.txt';

function searchLog($logfilepath, $searchQuery) {
    $fileresource = fopen($logfilepath, 'r');

    $occurences = array();
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        //now search in buffer
        if(strpos($buffer, $searchQuery) !== false) {
            $occurences[] = $buffer;
        }
    }

    return $occurences;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data source is a file and the definition of "entire line" is a newline delimiter, I would use [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to explode the data into an array and then loop through it:

```
function findLines($file_path, $needle) {
   $file_lines = file($file_path);
   foreach($file_lines as $line) {
      if(strpos($line, $needle) !== false) {
          $matching_lines[] = $line;
      }
   }
   return $matching_lines;
}

$needle = 'JohnDoe';
$log_entries = findLines('/path/to/log.txt', $needle);
```